# Nested pathnames in static pages generation in Svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am creating nested pathname routes as in below image:

[image]

These URLs to access them work as expected:
`/localhost/list/2020/prod/furn`
`/localhost/list/2020/prod/deco`
`/localhost/list/2021/prod/furn`

These URLs also work, but it should not.
`/localhost/list/blah/p/furn`
`/localhost/list/2020/xxx/deco`
`/localhost/list/furn`

PS:If `list` is removed from above URLs they don't work.

Sample URLs passed from svelte.config.js:
`entries: ['/list/2020/prod/furn', '/list/2021/prod/deco']`

Any clue how to achieve this to work as expected for static site generation is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`dec`, `cat`, and `act` are variables that are passed to your load functions and by default anything is allowed.

For static site generation you don't have to do anything, just don't link to invalid urls.
But I'd recommend to **add validation logic** in the [load function](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#loading):
When you encounter an invalid value respond with a error status like `{ status: 404 }`

Adding validation could break the `svelte-kit build` but you'd get useful errors like:
`> 404 /list/blah/p/furn (linked from /)`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Let me try this or any other way. I was in a assumption that if page doesn't exist in generated static file it throws 404.